# Read lines (two or more lines) from the output of AT command and put it to database

Tags: python, regex, at-command, filehandler

I want to read two lines from AT Command's output and do INSERT INTO table VALUES in python. The output of AT is always in two rows but it's a sequence, unlike open file and read it until the next limiter, but we have to wait.

anyway this is my code:

```
class SMSWait(self):
     def run(self):
         self.open()
         while self.ser.isOpen():
              time.sleep(1)
              SMSRead = 'AT+CMGL="ALL"\r\n'
              self.SendCommand(SMSRead, getline=True)

              while self.ser.inWaiting() > 0:
                   **data = self.ser.readall()
                   print data**
     def open(self):
         self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=115200, timeout=.1, rtscts=0)
         self.SendCommand('AT\r')
         self.SendCommand('AT+CMGF=1\r')
         self.ser.flushInput()
         self.ser.flushOutput()
     def SendCommand(self,command, getline=True):
         self.ser.write(command)
         data = ''
         if getline:
             data = self.ReadLine()
             data = filter(None, data)
         return data

     def ReadLine(self):
         data = self.ser.readline()
         return data
```

it will show the output:

```
AT+CMGL="ALL"

+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","+60xxxxxxxxx",,"15/02/05,14:13:47+28"
mydata43414242453564567578689789done

OK
```

now, how do i process this "sequence" output and ignoring the AT+CMGL="ALL" and "OK" and put them to database using "insert into" in one query. i don't have problem with accessing database using python. and i'm okay with regex. maybe someone could help me logically or script. thank you

Comment: you want to extract only two lines from your ouput? ignoring AT+CMGL="ALL" and "OK"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it. it seems that i have to put it all those lines inside a list and sort it, and reduce those 2 lines to 1 line. check it out

```
class SMSWait(self):
 def run(self):
     self.open()
     while 1:
         SMSRead = 'AT+CMGL="ALL"\r\n'
         self.SendCommand(SMSRead, getline=True)
         data = self.ser.readall()
         time.sleep(2)
         datalist.append(data)
         if any('+CMGL:' in d for d in datalist):
             if 'AT' in datalist: datalist.remove['AT']
             if any('\r\n' in d for d in datalist): datalist = [d.replace('\r\n', '') for d in datalist]
             if any('\r' in d for d in datalist): datalist   = [d.replace('\r', '') for d in datalist]
             if any('\n' in d for d in datalist): datalist   = [d.replace('\n', '') for d in datalist]
             if any('OK' in d for d in datalist): datalist   = [d.replace('OK', '') for d in datalist]
             datalist = filter(None, datalist)
             split_data = datalist[0].split('+CMGL: ')
             split_data = filter(None, split_data)
```

then from here we can start to process the data from list value one by one

```
             for s in split_data:
                 '''your code here'''
```